# How to connect to MySQL Database from eMbedded Visual C++

Tags: c++, mysql, embedded, windows-ce, windows-embedded

How can I connect to a remote Mysql database, from Cpp code using Microsoft eMbedded Visual C++ (which is configured for a special board running WindowsCE)? I have downloaded the source files for Mysql C and C++ Connector/APIs but; their 'make' or installation process is pretty complicated and valid only for Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found that, there are no ports of mysql-client to any mobile platform. If anyone has any other information, please feel free to answer this question.